# Active VHDL: Design Unit Declaration Expected

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this code below.  Every other file works however when I tried to compile this file I get

```
# Error: COMP96_0019: file_io.vhd : (30, 6): Keyword 'begin' expected.
# Error: COMP96_0016: file_io.vhd : (30, 11): Design unit declaration expected.
```

The error is for the segment shown below.

```
data : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
initial_addr:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
rst_iar_bar:in std_logic; 
clk:in std_logic;
wb_data:out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);

----fetch
instruction:out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

----IDRD
idrd_srcA,idrd_srcB,idrd_data:out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
idrd_opcode,idrd_rd_addr,idrd_rs2_addr:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

idrd_addorsub,idrd_lv,idrd_alu_op,idrd_B_select,idrd_saturate,idrd_reg_wr:out std_logic;
idrd_sel: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

----IFID
ifid_opcode,ifid_rs1_addr,ifid_rs2_addr,ifid_rd_addr:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
```

Below is the full file, I need to figure out how to fix this error!  I am following an example that was created by my professor however it is not working properly for me.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all; 
use std.textio.all;     
use ieee.numeric_std.all;  
use txt_util.all;

entity fileio is
end fileio;


architecture fileio of fileio is
signal data:std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
signal initial_addr,idrd_rs2_addr,idrd_rd_addr,idrd_opcode,ifid_opcode,ifid_rs1_addr,ifid_rs2_addr,
ifid_rd_addr:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal reset: std_logic;    -- 

signal Instr_out: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);


signal clk: std_logic;  --  
signal idrd_addorsub,idrd_lv,idrd_alu_op,idrd_saturate,idrd_B_select,idrd_reg_wr:std_logic;
signal instruction_in:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal wb_data,idrd_srcA,idrd_srcB,idrd_data: std_logic_vector(63 downto 0); 
signal idrd_sel:std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
signal instruction:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
constant period:time:=20ns;     


    data : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    initial_addr:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    rst_iar_bar:in std_logic; 
    clk:in std_logic;
    wb_data:out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);

    ----fetch
    instruction:out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

    ----IDRD
    idrd_srcA,idrd_srcB,idrd_data:out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    idrd_opcode,idrd_rd_addr,idrd_rs2_addr:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    idrd_addorsub,idrd_lv,idrd_alu_op,idrd_B_select,idrd_saturate,idrd_reg_wr:out std_logic;
    idrd_sel: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

    ----IFID
    ifid_opcode,ifid_rs1_addr,ifid_rs2_addr,ifid_rd_addr:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);




begin                 
uut:cellliteunit 
port map(
    instruction=>instruction,
    idrd_srcA=>idrd_srcA,
    idrd_srcB=>idrd_srcB,
    idrd_data=>idrd_data,
    idrd_opcode=>idrd_opcode,
    idrd_rd_addr=>idrd_rd_addr, 
    idrd_rs2_addr=>idrd_rs2_addr,
    idrd_addorsub=>idrd_addorsub,idrd_lv=>idrd_lv,idrd_alu_op=>idrd_alu_op,
    idrd_B_select=>idrd_B_select,idrd_saturate=>idrd_saturate,idrd_reg_wr=>idrd_reg_wr, 
    idrd_sel=>idrd_sel,
    ifid_opcode=>ifid_opcode,ifid_rs1_addr=>ifid_rs1_addr,
    ifid_rs2_addr=>ifid_rs2_addr,ifid_rd_addr=>ifid_rd_addr,
    data=>data,
    initial_addr=>initial_addr,
    rst_iar_bar=>rst_iar_bar,
    clk=>clk,
    wb_data=>wb_data
    );       

a:process       
begin
    data<=X"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"; 
    wait for 6*period;

    data<=X"0000000100000000";

    wait;
end process;

b:process
begin    
    initial_addr<=X"0";

    rst_iar_bar<='0', '1' after period;
    wait;
end process b;

clock:process
begin
    clk<='1';
    for i in 0 to 100 loop
        wait for period;
        clk<=not clk;
    end loop;
    wait;
end process clock;  


write_p:process
    file outfile:text;          
    variable r:string(1 to 5);
    variable s:string(1 to 5);
    variable t:string(1 to 5);

begin                
    for j in 1 to 15 loop
        wait for 2*period;
        case instruction(15 downto 12) is
            ...
            ...
            ...
        end case;
    end loop;
end fileio;
```

Comment: You are missing `end` for the `for` loop at the end

Comment: It is there in the original code, just accidentally snipped it out!

Comment: This is a simple typographical error, thus [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You've copied a chunk of a port list into your declaration region, and forgotten to turn the port declarations into signal declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The segment you showed in your post does not belong into an architecture.
`data : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);` etc are port declarations(notice the direction specifier `in`). I presume that's a copy and paste error from the entity declaration of `cellliteunit`.

Also notice that each identifier in this block is already given to a signal in your archticture of exactly the same type. I cannot test this without all your other files, but I presume you simply need to delete the block from lines 29 to 45.

**EDIT**
The component declaration is missing in your architecture. The block from line 29 to 45 seems to be it. It should probably be lookling like this:

```
component cellliteunit
    port(
       data : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
       initial_addr:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
       [...]
       ifid_opcode,ifid_rs1_addr,ifid_rs2_addr,ifid_rd_addr:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end component
```

Comment: When I do that it says that the for the UUT:cellliteunit 
"Cannot find component declaration"

Comment: d'oh, I didn't read the code thoroughly enough. I have edited my answer.